# Application Error on new Heroku app

Tags: node.js, macos, heroku

I know this question has been answered a lot, but I still can't figure out a solution to my problem. I've created a little app which is supposed to work with the Slack webhook. Locally, it works just fine - I use `node app` in order to launch it.

I've created my app on Heroku, pushed my files (`Procfile app.js hellobot.js package.json`)

But when I visit `http://slackbot2.herokuapp.com/`, I get an Application Error message.

I already tried the log but I get this :

> 2015-06-11T23:39:05.967607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=slackbot2.herokuapp.com request_id=b3783c70-306b-4528-9d81-4e8ab43e9132 fwd="*******" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

This `heroku run rails console` and `heroku run rake db:migrate` won't work. `bash: rails command not found`. Rails and Rake are installed on my Mac (OSX 10.10.4). Those were the only solutions that worked for others .. But not me.

Comment: Try restarting the app, `heroku restart -a slackbot2`. If it still fails the same way, then make sure your data is initialized (seeded) properly. Is the data on Heroku the same data content you currently have on your local server? What happens if you first do, `heroku run bash`, and then at the command prompt, enter, `rails console`?

Comment: Yes, the same data are on Heroku and on my local server .

Comment: @lurker If I do this a prompt is shown and after it says "rails command not found" . I don't understand, I followed their little tuto about node.js, and the sample application was working

Comment: That seems odd. Is your app setup on Heroku as a rails application?

Comment: @lurker How do I know that ?

Comment: Login to your Heroku account at www.heroku.com and verify settings there. When you create a Heroku app, they offer a couple of different app platforms. Rails is only one of them. How exactly did you create your Heroku app?

Comment: I just clicked on the "+" on the top right corner , and I followed their steps to put my files on their git.

Comment: Login to your Heroku account. On the left you'll see a link called "Personal Apps". Click on that and near the bottom of the page is a list of your apps, and you should see "slackbot2". Click on that and it will take you to your app configuration page, the Resources tab. You should see how many web dynos you have allocated (needs to be at least 1X), it should show the startup command (something like `bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`, and it should show you a link to your database. I'm not sure, but you might have to pay $9/mo for the Hobby Basic data for minimum functionality.

Comment: The startup command is `node app` I don't have any database.

Comment: Therein lies the issue. It's setup as a node app, not a rails app. You'll need to read their online documentation to get instructions for setting up a Rails app.

Comment: Yes it is, and it is a node application. How am I supposed to resolve my problem now ?

Comment: You mean it's a Rails app using node.js? You'll need to read the Heroku documentation for setup.

Comment: No it's not a rails app, it's a node app. I was just using rails console and everything because this is the only solution that worked for others, even on node apps

Comment: OK, that's why the rails command doesn't work on Heroku. A node app doesn't assume rails. You'll need to read the Heroku documention on setting up a node app.

Comment: I read it .. It's the same, I did the sample application setup and it worked and now that I created my own application it doesn't work anymore ..

Comment: I have done Rails on Heroku, but not Node. Can you do `heroku run bash` and run `node` on your app at the prompt for debugging? The fact your database doesn't show up is troubling, though. Is it Postgresql?

Comment: Yes node is launched. I don't use any databases ..

Comment: OK, sorry, when you said your data was the same in both places I assumed it was via a database. Did you happen to try the restart command I suggested?

Comment: Yes I did this one a lot. I was speaking about the files sorry. Still the same error H10 App crashed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened with me. As far as I can remember, the reason for this is the port you used in the application. Heroku will not run your app on port 8080 or 3000, instead it will be some random port. Use this code to fix the problem.

`var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;`

Use this code to start the server.

`app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});`